# cannot open include files assert.h matlab system()

Tags: visual-studio-2008, matlab, opencv

I'm trying to run Matlab code on Windows 7 (64 bit) pre-installed with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. Matlab code has .cpp files which needs to be compiled with opencv.

I'm using:

```
system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe"  /I"C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv"  camshift_wrapper.c');
```

I'm getting error as:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for x64 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. 

camshift_wrapper.c

c:\opencv2.1\include\opencv\cxtypes.h(52) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'assert.h': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include` to your argument string of the system command.

Comment: You should use environment variables or relative path, because in different systems paths can be different.

Comment: thanx but now im getting 
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
how should  i mention "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib" once in \link so that al the libraries are automatically included

Comment: if i mention all the .lib file in /link option iam getting error 

LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined